# Change active object line

Tags: objects, interface, customization, selection-tools, object-mode

Good Morning,

I have Blender 2.92 and I think I have a problem with the orange lines that the active objects have in the 'Object Mode'. Active objects have a double orange line, but I have seen in videos that other people have a single line (similar to how it looks from 'Edit Mode').

[image: Capture 1]
[image: Capture 2]

I would like to know if you can remove that double line and put a single one.

Greetings and thanks

Edit: I do not know if the link will work, it is the first time that I upload something to google drive.
[File .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ssreeXlzTIUCUfjK8J7LKwTJrguUbIyr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This may be a graphic issue as well caused by GPU, can you share your default file?

Comment: Sure, it's already uploaded.

Comment: As I have thought, it works completely fine to me as it should... This means that this is probably due to your HW, what GPU are you using? I would recommend to try newer or different version of Blender or update your GPU drivers

Answer (score 0):

In case of this being done by your GPU, the only options left for you are:

- Update or reinstall GPU drivers.
- Use a different version of Blender, try the newest one first or reinstall Blender.
- Lookup if your GPU has similar issues within different users
- Sent it to Blender developers and maybe they will fix it
- Use a different GPU (Impossible today, I know)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help MicoCG,<br/><br/>

My graphics card is old, it is an ATI HD Radeon 5750 and they no longer update their drivers, but I have the latest ones installed.<br/><br/>

As for Blender, I can't update it because the latest version, 2.93, doesn't work on Windows 7, which is the OS I have. The latest supported version is 2.92.<br/><br/>

I will try to contact the developers, but I don't think they will make any changes to an old version.<br/><br/>

Best regards and thanks again